# Angular project template with ASP.NET Core. API Test

Tags: .net, angular, .net-7.0

I have created new app using following command.

`dotnet new angular`

I have added new controller and want to test using Postman.

How can I find the address of API which is running locally after executing following command.

`dotnet run`

As I understand when I execute following command:

`dotnet run`

It start both applications (Angular, Web API) simultaneously.

When I go to localhost it shows the UI / Angular App.

I want to find URL of the API to test it before deployment using Postman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> dotnet run
>
> It start both applications (Angular, Web API) simultaneously.

`dotnet run` runs only .net app. Run `ng serve` to run angular app.

To find the correct endpoint, check `launchsettings.json` from `Properties` folder. Under `profiles >> applicationUrl` you will see something like this:

```
"applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5000;http://localhost:5001"
```

Comment: Indeed https://localhost:5000 was the endpoint I was looking for, Thanks. 
Now I encounter another issue, I can't find out what is the URL of deployed API. 

Where I can find it ?

Answer (score 1):

When running command
`dotnet run`
in terminal, it should print something similar to

```
Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
```

That will be your back-end URL

Comment: That's correct, but I am getting two of those: `Now listening on: http://localhost:7196`
and `Now listening on: http://localhost:5105` when I press any of those (crtl + enter), it opens a cmd and redirects me to `localhost:44493` and shows Angular UI (website itself), it doesn't matter which one I press on, both does same. Once I press above links In the terminal it writes :`info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaProxy.SpaProxyLaunchManager[0]
 No SPA development server running at https://localhost:44493 found.` 
and `SPA proxy is not ready. Returning temporary landing page.` UI works perfectly.